# A double integral question which I made up to test my understanding

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So I wish to find the value of the integral $\int_{C}f$, where $f = \sin(xy)$ and $C = ([-1,1] \times[-1,1]) \backslash \{(x,y):\|(x,y)\|<1 \}$. So $C$ is basically the closed unit cube minus the unit open ball. So the standard trick is to note that $C \subset A = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ and $f$ is certainly a continuous function on $A$. So certainly $\int_{A}f$ exists. Further the boundary of $C$ has measure zero. Therefore $\int_{C}f$ exists. Now if $\psi$ is the characteristic function of $C$, then

\begin{equation}
\int_{C}f = \int_{A}f\psi
\end{equation}

Now invoking Fubini's theorem, we get that $\int_{A} f \psi = \int_{-1}^{1}(\int_{-1}^1f\psi \ dy) \ dx$. Now the first integral  boils down to the following

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}f\psi \ dy = \int_{-1}^{1}\sin(xy)\psi\ dy = \int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin(xy)\ dy+ \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1}\sin(xy)\ dx
\end{equation}

Now

\begin{equation}
\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1}\sin(xy)\ dx = \frac{-\cos(xy)}{x} \Bigg|_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1} = \frac{\cos(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}
\end{equation}

Similarly
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin(xy)\ dy = \frac{\cos(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}f\psi \ dy = 2\left( \frac{\cos(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}  \right)
\end{equation}

But how do I calculate

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\cos(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}
\end{equation}

If my calculations are right, this last integral is not defined. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the last integral is not defined? Shouldn't the divergent $1/x$-term cancel out? However, it looks like an analytic solution of this is probably not possible. A different idea would be to introduce polar coordinates for the integration over the unit circle, but than you get something like $\operatorname{sin}(r^2 \operatorname{sin}(\phi) \operatorname{cos}(\phi))$, which is also not solvable. Did you already try Wolframalpha for that?

Comment: The last integrand is not defined at 0

Comment: Yes, but the singularity is removable and doesn't come from any problems with the initial integral, see the answer from Gae. S.

Comment: Yes I got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$ your $\int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdots+\int^{1}_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdots$ part is just $0$.

Unsurprisingly, it is also the case that $\frac{\cos(x\sqrt{1-x^2})}x-\frac{\cos x}x$ extends continuously to a function such that $g(0)=0$.

Comment: Right thanks that makes sense.